# Change track not working with Entity framework core

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I want to track the changes to entities that I update using Entity framework core. The issue is that it always gives me no changes but database is updated. I am using PostgreSQL database with entity framework core.Below is my configurations:

**Context.cs:**

```
    public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public QRDAParsingContext(DbContextOptions<QRDAParsingContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            //options.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BloggingDatabase"].ConnectionString)
        }
        public DbSet<Individual> Individual { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            JwtTokenDefinitions.LoadFromConfiguration(Configuration);
            services.ConfigureJwtAuthentication();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<QRDAParsingContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataAccessPostgreSqlProvider")));

            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                   new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
            });
            // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents

            var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
            corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
            corsBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
            corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin(); // For anyone access.
            corsBuilder.AllowCredentials();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("SiteCorsPolicy", corsBuilder.Build());
            });

        }
```

**Code that gives issue:**

```
 context.Entry(updateIndividualNew).State = EntityState.Modified;
 context.SaveChanges();
 var changes = context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
```

Comment: You need to get changes before to save changes in database

Comment: `SaveChanges` applies all modifications (`Added`, `Modified` and `Deleted`) to the database. After that call, all entries are set to `Unchanged`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is working. But, in my previous projects it works after hiiting saveChanges.Can you please explain?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "previous project". AFAIK it never worked that way (neither in EF6 and below, nor in any EF Core version). Except if you were using some buggy EF Core version.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have example how to tracking entity changes and save to db infromation about changes
https://github.com/siasty/EntityChangeTracking.git

```
context.Entry(updateIndividualNew).State = EntityState.Modified;
DisplayTrackedEntities(context.ChangeTracker);
context.SaveChanges();


 private static void DisplayTrackedEntities(ChangeTracker changeTracker)
 {

            var entries = changeTracker.Entries();
            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Table Name: {0}", entry.Entity.GetType().Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", entry.State);
                foreach (var prop in entry.OriginalValues.Properties)
                {
                    var originalValue = entry.OriginalValues[prop].ToString();
                    var currentValue =  entry.CurrentValues[prop].ToString();
                    if (originalValue != currentValue)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Orginal: Column Name {0} value {1} ", prop.Name, entry.OriginalValues[prop].ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Current: Column Name {0} value {1}", prop.Name, entry.CurrentValues[prop].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

}
```